# Touch Event clicking UIImageView while rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My `ImageView` rotates but while it rotates it doesn't recognize touches on itself.
Do you think it's okay if I create a button via code that's over the `ImageView` that recognizes the touch?

Comment: Your question is unclear without an example of the code you're using; we don't know how the ImageView is implemented, why it doesn't recognize touches, or what your button approach is that would or would not be "okay"

Comment: (It seems pretty clear!)  Yeah, it's perfectly ok, and normal, to make a "blank button" and just have your trick image underneath.  Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an animation is applied on any `UIView` or any subclass object of a UIView like `UIImageView`, `UIButton` etc then it does not detect touch events because when an animation is applied to a view, the animated property changes to its end value right away. what you are actually seeing on screen is the presentation layer of your views layer.

**To answer your question**, Yes, you can make a UIButton that covers up the area of the UIImageView to detect touch events on it. That sounds like the easiest to implement option in this case.

Apart from that, this link may also help you in the process. [Hit testing animating layers](http://ronnqvist.tumblr.com/post/21228285860/hit-testing-animating-layers)

Comment: Thanks that answers my question :)
It might sound funny but if someday maybe I'll upload this app to the AppStore. Will I get problems with apple maybe because it's not the best solution ?

Comment: No, it is just implementation, Apple wouldn't know neither would care about this. It is not against their guidelines of code